# JPA and Postgres: Querying a foreign key

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-boot

I have two entities,

Rater, that has a one to many mapping to Rating,

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "Rater")
public class Rater {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rater")
    private Set<Rating> ratings;

    /** constructor, getters, setters, etc. */
}
```

and Rating, with a foreign key to the Rater's id

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Rating")
    public class Rating {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Rater rater;
}
```

I want to find all the ratings made by rater with id 3. I would accomplish this in Postgres with a query such as:

`SELECT rating FROM Rating rating, Rater rater WHERE rating.rater_id = rater.id AND rater.id = 3;`

When I translate this into my JPA REST API

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "rating", path = "ratings")
public interface RatingRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Rating, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT rating FROM Rating rating WHERE rating.rater.id = :id")
    List<Rating> findByRaterId(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

I get an error when I make the call

`ERROR: column rating0_.id does not exist`

How do I properly query a foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
```

to

```
@JoinColumn(name = "rater_id", nullable = false)
```